# Crash when running FTPClient listFiles method

Tags: java, ant, ftp

When I try to run the method listFiles in my Java program (already connected to server) suddenly it crash and the error I get in netbeans is next:

**run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:**

```
The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
Pattern cannot be resolved to a type
MatchResult cannot be resolved to a type
PatternMatcher cannot be resolved to a type
_matcher_ cannot be resolved
Perl5Matcher cannot be resolved to a type
pattern cannot be resolved
Perl5Compiler cannot be resolved to a type
MalformedPatternException cannot be resolved to a type
result cannot be resolved or is not a field
_matcher_ cannot be resolved
pattern cannot be resolved or is not a field
result cannot be resolved or is not a field
_matcher_ cannot be resolved
result cannot be resolved or is not a field
result cannot be resolved or is not a field
result cannot be resolved or is not a field
result cannot be resolved or is not a field
result cannot be resolved or is not a field
result cannot be resolved or is not a field
result cannot be resolved or is not a field
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.RegexFTPFileEntryParserImpl.<init>(RegexFTPFileEntryParserImpl.java:19)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.ConfigurableFTPFileEntryParserImpl.<init>(ConfigurableFTPFileEntryParserImpl.java:57)
```

.
.
.

But it compiled. It looks like if it is not finding the org.apache.oro libraries and i added them to the project (jakarta-oro-2.0.8), but it keep happening.

Any idea on what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance for your help,
Pablo.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was able to solve this using a newer version of commons-net 3.3

Discarding older version of commons-net should resolve the issue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Remember it's a **Q&A** site and your responses to a question are supposed to be valid answers. In your case, consider using `comment` or speak in chat room instead once you have enough reputation.